# Can't fit appbar and the activity in the same screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-appbarlayout

I'm building a android app and im using the android material design app bar. I wanted to fit the activity in the screen with the appbar and I cant do it.

I have this line of code:

```
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

This line allow me to fit the activity in the screen but some content is below the screen. Both appbar and the content are different xml files (don't know if they are consider as fragments). Can someone help to fit the content in the screen without being on top of the appbar?

If I use this line:

[image]

And without it:

[image]

Comment: I want the toolbar/tablayout like the first but the bottom like the second one.

Comment: i didint get what you actual mean ..please clear your quistian .. and also post your xml code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is solutions to your problem.
**case 1:** if you does not want to scroll or collapse tabs and toolbar(i.e. your content is not scroll-able):

You should not use `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`, instead of it set **layout_marginTop** to root view of content up-to height of(toolbar+tabs). If you are using standard heights then it is **48+48 = 96dp** (you should check and verify these dimensions).

**case 2:**
If you have scroll able content or want  to scroll able content, then just use NestedScrollView as a root viewGroup of content and stop worrying about behavior. It will work correct automatically.

Comment: This really worked. I thought that would be more complex :)

Answer (score 0):

try this way this worked me fine

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="192dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/rsz_bg_cover"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="#EEE" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope this will helps you