# Extend CoordinatorLayout height from screen height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

In my layout height of the CoodinatorLayout is larger than screen size that makes the content at bottom cut. Is there a possibility to increase the size of the Coordinator layout?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of CoordinatorLayout child's scroll_flags `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

may be this post help you out.
[Can't fit appbar and the activity in the same screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743001/cant-fit-appbar-and-the-activity-in-the-same-screen/35772450)  . That's my answer there.